# How to set initial value of form control if form is dynamic in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using trying to make something like fb, I have following problem:

I want to have comment for for each post as fb does, But I want to check on form submit which form is submitted, mainly on which post user commented. How can I Do this:

I have the following Code:

```html
<article class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">

  <div class="post-body">

    <div class="post-content">
      {{ post.content }}
    </div>

    <ul class="comment-area">

      <li>
        <form class="comment-form" [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onComment()">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="../../assets/profile.jpg">
          <input type="text" 
            class="comment-input" 
            formControlName="comment"
            placeholder="Enter your comment">

          <button type="submit" class="comment-sub">Send</button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</article>
```

I have post id in post._id but how can I pass this to the TS file, I tried [ngModel] but angular show deprecation error...

I have the following TS CODE:

```js
commentForm = new FormGroup({
        comment: new FormControl('', [PostValidator.notEmpty]),
        postId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
```

I want to somehow get post id on commentForm > postId,

Please HELP

Comment: if you has the value in a variable you can use `comment:new FormControl(variable,[PostValidator.notEmpty])` other option is use, after create the commentForm use pathValue/setValue: `commentForm.setValue({comment:variable,postId:otherVariable})`

Comment: [Coincidence, or a double post with a new member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648963/how-to-set-form-control-value-if-formcontrol-value-is-inside-ngfor-loop-in-react)

Comment: Sorry I wanted urgent Help so I created fake account using disposable mail service

Comment: No one was replying there

Comment: Thank you sir, I got the idea

Comment: Did you try (ngSubmit)="onComment(post.id)" ?

Comment: yes sir Actually I am using this implementation now, is there any better approach, what about using viewChild ? How you all guys handle this issue sir?